# wxpython wx.Messagebox EVT_CLOSE bind

Tags: python, wxpython, messagebox

i am using wxpython and trying to make a messagebox that has bind function when the user close the messagebox, but when i close the mesagebox, won't work and returns except, what i need to change?

```
FinishMessage=wx.MessageBox("message for you", "title", wx.OK)
FinishMessage.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseCheckSwitchesMessage)
```

except:

```
    FinishMessage.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseCheckSwitchesMessage)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'Bind'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because MessageBox is a function that opens a MessageDialog and returns the button the user pressed as an integer. If you need to bind events you have to use MessageDialog directly.